# Keep iPhone UIButton Highlighted

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I have the following code snippets:

```
@interface Foo: UIViewController {
  ...
  UIButton *myButton;
  ...
}
```

@implementation Foo

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
  ...
  myButton.highlighted = YES;
  ...
}
```

When I run the app, the button is highlighted in blue (default behavior). It works as I expected.

But after pressing the button once, the button is no longer highlighted.

Then, I created an `IBAction` `highlightButton` to handle `Touch Up Inside` event where I explicitly call `myButton.highlighted = Yes;`. Unfortunately, the button highlight still does not stay.

How can I keep it highlighted in blue even after being pressed?

Comment: Would it be easier to just change the color of the button? :)

Comment: See my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934861/uibutton-border-and-background-image).

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

I am not using any image. I just use text by calling "[myButton setTitle:@"Foo" forState:UIControlStateNormal]".

Comment: You should be able to do this anyway. My process was to take a screenshot of a blank, **highlighted** button, and set that as the background image for the **selected** state. Then instead of changing the **highlighted** property, I changed the **selected** property. You can set the background image in Interface Builder and never worry about it again, just turn on or off the **selected** property.

Answer (score 45):

The solution is to do `[button setHighlighted:YES]` in the next runloop:

```
- (void)highlightButton:(UIButton *)b { 
    [b setHighlighted:YES];
}

 - (IBAction)onTouchup:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self performSelector:@selector(highlightButton:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0.0];
}
```

Comment: Thank you Werner. Could you possibly explain why we have to set it in the next runloop ? Does the button not get redrawn when we call this particular method ?

Comment: Problem is the iOS framework calls onTouchup (the event handler) and afterwards unhighlights the button (setHighlighted:NO). So calling setHighlighted in the event handler doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 13):

The simplest code is here.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [button setHighlighted:YES];
});
```

Comment: the best option. Does not make the button flash shortly to the normal state after user raises the finger.

Comment: Not to mention that this way permits you to perform this with multiple buttons in a view and keep it VERY neat.

Comment: Just wondering.. the "gdc" block here is released from memory after it's done right?

Answer (score 7):

An alternate way to run this is by sending a block to the main operation queue:

```
-(void)onTouchup:(UIButton*) button
{
    [NSOperationQueue.mainQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{ button.highlighted = YES; }];
}
```

Comment: Oh wow. How on earth would I have discovered this without StackOverflow?