# Can't set UIButton.highlighted to NO

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I have a `UITableViewCell` with `UIButton` in each cell. When the button is pressed I set its state to highlighted like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7418662/1313939) answer:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(doHighlight:) withObject:[cell.subviews objectAtIndex:2] afterDelay:0.0];
```

Then I do this:

```
- (void)doHighlight:(UIButton *)sender {

    if (sender.highlighted) {
        [sender setHighlighted:NO];
    } else {
    [sender setHighlighted:YES];
    }
}
```

But the button not only is just not highlighted at all, not speaking about the fact that I should be able to UNhighlight it.

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Comment: Are u sure that [cell.subviews objectAtIndex:2] a UIButton?

Comment: From which function you are calling this `performSelector`. It is mentioned in the post that, when the button is pressed, in that case how you get the `cell` instance?

Comment: @HRM from the function which is assigned to be the one when the button is pressed, an ordinary `target:self selector:@selector(copyPressedFromCell:)` and I create a button in `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: So, y u taking button from cell. You shoud get the button in copyPressedFromCell,rt? Also, I dnt knw, whether u creating the button in willDisplayCell causing any issues..

Comment: @HRM the problem here is not with the Button itself, but either with `delay` of which I can't get rid of, or it's with the `if` statement in the `doHighlight` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `UIButton`'s `selected` property. It does not require any `delay` and it works brilliantly with this type of things:

```
if (!sender.selected) {
    [sender setSelected:YES];
    [cell addSubview:hiddenButton];
    [self performSelector:@selector(doHighlight:) withObject:sender];
} else {
    [sender setSelected:NO];
    [self performSelector:@selector(doUnHighlight:) withObject:sender];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution you are looking for. I have modified my answer

```
 UIButton *button=[cell.subviews objectAtIndex:2];

//I am adding these five lines to ensure the different 
//states of the button to achieve your highlighted state goal. 

UIImage *highlightImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"highlight.png"];//Also used  when button is selected
UIImage *normalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"normal.png"];
[button setBackgroundImage:normalImage forState:(UIControlStateHighlighted)];
[button setBackgroundImage:highlightImage forState:(UIControlStateSelected)];
[button setBackgroundImage:normalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 [self performSelector:@selector(doHighlight:) withObject:[cell.subviews objectAtIndex:2]];

-(IBAction) doHighlight:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        UIButton *btn=(UIButton*)sender;
        if (btn.isSelected) {
            [btn setSelected:NO];
        }
        else
        {
            [btn setSelected:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you are wrong.There IS a big sense in using that `delay` thing. Without it, the button won't be highlighted until it's tapped again. And even if I use the `delay` with your decision it hives me nothing.